# Can't get PHP script to run when launched from Aptana Studio

Tags: php

I've been using notepad++ for web development (currently html, css, and some php and mysql). I decided to dive into an IDE to see if I could cut down on development time and have more power than notepad++.

I grabbed Aptana yesterday and, after harassing it for a few hours, have finally gotten everything up and running. The only problem is that my web pages, which are `.php`'s, do not execute any of their included `.php` code in the browser.

as an example:

```
<?php
echo "IT WORKS WOOO";
?>
```

ought to print `IT WORKS WOOO` smack in the middle of my blank test page, and yet it does not. I checked to see if I had somehow forgotten how to do an echo statement and ran it on my desktop, using notepad++, and it worked just fine.

I have the php plugin, have used the php perspective to write it and have launched it as a php web page, but nothing makes it execute the php within.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think Aptana comes with a PHP interpreter... just a PHP editor.

Comment: I'm having it launch the file through chrome (or firefox), though. Unless it's still tied in that way somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to run through the [setup for the PHP Plugin](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Developing_with_the_Aptana_PHP_Plugin) again, to make sure you configured everything correctly.

I use an external WAMP server, as I can better mirror the environment I am developing for. They [have a guide on how to set that up](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Configuring_Aptana_Studio_to_use_an_external_web_server), too.